# Trouble running Django tests - No module named

Tags: django

I'm working on what could be a reusable Django app for training registration - taking it out of a larger project.  Unfortunately, I'm having a problem running the tests.  I'm using Django 1.6 and here is my file structure:

```
training/
  test_env/
    settings.py
    urls.py
     wsgi.py
  training/
    tests/
      test_forms.py
      test_views.py
      test_models.py
    admin.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    urls.py
    views.py
  manage.py
```

The only command that will run the tests is:

```
python manage.py test training.tests
```

If I use `python manage.py test` or `python manage.py test training`, I get three errors - one for each test_*.py file: `No module named training.tests.test_views`, etc.

Any suggestions?

Comment: is there an `__init__.py` in the `tests` directory ? also, import all the `test*.py` files into `__init__.py`

Comment: And change runner to py.test-django (https://github.com/pelme/pytest_django)

Comment: @karthikr, there is an `__init__.py` in the tests directory. I used the import method when this app was in a Django 1.3 project, and it worked just fine.  However, in this v1.6 setup no tests were found.  When I changed the names of the files to `test_*.py`, they were autodiscovered, but something isn't quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

My project folder and app folder have the same name.  When I changed the project name, the tests run fine.